# Mastodon Post [toot] Embed - Change to Light Theme

Tags: javascript, embed, oembed, mastodon

Mastodon offers an embed option for individual posts/toots by adding `/embed` at the end of the post URL. However, it seems that Mastodon always [defaults to a dark theme](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/user/preferences/#:%7E:text=mastodon%20defaults%20to%20a%20dark%20theme). For example:

```
https://mstdn.social/@eladratson/109366816613595747/embed
```

[image]

I'm looking for a way to generate an embed URL that will render the same post but with Mastodon's light theme.

I've tried using `theme=` as a query option in the URL like this:

`https://mstdn.social/@eladratson/109366816613595747/embed?theme=mastodon_light` or `mstdn_light`

but it doesn't work. Anyone knows how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not appear to be an option to do this in the default Mastodon embed options. They use an iframe, which then pulls in CSS from the Mastodon CDN, and the only styles defined there are the default darker Mastodon colour.

You could use the API to grab the content directly, and style it yourself.